# How to create Firestore index on a dynamic field in a map?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Firestore document structure:

```
status: "active"
updatedAt: October 8, 2020 at 3:44:29 PM UTC+3
accessControl (map) 
  OwiGbKk37XQmXjrFok8J7cXEtOr1: "write"
```

I have a query as follows:

```
const uid = 'OwiGbKk37XQmXjrFok8J7cXEtOr1'
await db
  .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
  .orderBy('status', 'desc')
  .orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc')
  .where('accessControl.' + uid, '==', 'write')
  .get()
```

As long as I remove the `.orderBy` clauses and avoid adding more `.where` clauses this works. If I want to order or filter tho, Firestore asks me to add an index with the specific UID which is not possible for scale purposes and the fact that this field is dynamically generated.

I have tried single field index exceptions to no prevail.

Firestore documentation doesn't cover this typical case for some reason, any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This document structure isn't going to work with the kind of queries you want to do.  You should instead consider using a list field that contains the UIDs of the users that can write:

```
status:      "active"
updatedAt:   October 8, 2020 at 3:44:29 PM UTC+3
writeAccess: (list) 
  [0] OwiGbKk37XQmXjrFok8J7cXEtOr1
```

Then you can query it like this using array-contains:

```
const uid = 'OwiGbKk37XQmXjrFok8J7cXEtOr1'
await db
  .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
  .where('writeAccess', 'array-contains', uid)
  .orderBy('status', 'desc')
  .orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc')
  .get()
```

Please see the documentation for [array queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) for more information.

Comment: Hi @Doug, thanks for this, it was exactly how I solved it! Root answer to the question is the fact that Firestore requires all map keys to be indexed. So maintaining dynamic key indexes is not scalable and should be avoided at any cost.