# Flutter Firestore Composite Index with variable item not realistic?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, composite-index

I just created a StreamBuilder that has this stream:

```
      stream: db
          .collection('GearLockerItems')
          .where('inPack.$packID', isEqualTo: true)
          .orderBy('itemName')
          .snapshots(),
```

When I ran the code, it didn't work at first, and when I checked the debug console. I saw a link I had to click and then it went and build a composite index and it worked!

But.... the composite index if for that specific variable `$packID` which means everytime I click on a new "pack" in my app to get this list, it wont work until I manually click to create the index....

This doesn't seem intuitive fro an app that lots of user could use, I can't manually index each item. Is there anyway around this or do I need to rething my entire db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to flatten the `'inPack.$packID'` to be part of the document fields rather than inside an object.

<del>Another is to list all possible options and create indexes for them, takes some time yes but gets the job done. I would not follow this approach as it will be prune to future errors if new packs are created and an index is not created for those. unless if you create a cloud function to automate the indexes creation. But again too many indexes will increase the size and will be counterproductive to "write operations" performance.</del>

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292347/how-to-create-firestore-index-on-a-dynamic-field-in-a-map) as it is relevant to your case.

#### UPDATE:

Removed the suggestion about doing the composite indexes programmatically as it is not supported. For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715581/how-we-can-create-compound-index-programmatically-in-gcp-firestore-database-in-n) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960930/how-to-automatically-create-indexes-for-cloud-firestore).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ended up going with a sub-container which solved my problem and a few future issues I was tryign to wrap my head around. 

The tip on using the array contains in that links was also helpful, thanks! It seems maps can make things more difficult...

Comment: You are welcome! I just knew that creating indexes programmatically is not possible and thus will be updating my answer accordingly.